# A loop that goes through two lists and return a list containing the larger elements?

Tags: python, list, loops, element

for example,

```
listOne = [1,2,6]
listTwo = [3,2,4]

checkLists(listOne, listTwo)

should return [3,2,6]
```

1 < 3 therefore [3,?,?]

2 = 2 therefore [3,2,?]

6 > 4 therefore [3,2,6]

I have recently started python and don't know how to use a loop that checks two lists at once.

Comment: Hint: [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/1903116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make a new list.
You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through both lists at once.
You can use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) to give you the greater of two items.

```
def checkLists(a, b):
    return [max(ai, bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b)]
```

This gives:

```
>>> checkLists([1,2,6], [3,2,4])
[3, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in function here:

```
result_iter = map(max, list_one, list_two)
```

which will create a list on Python 2 and an iterator (a map object) on Python 3 - if you do need a list, on Python 3 wrap the `map` with `list()`:

```
result_list = list(map(max, list_one, list_two))
```

---

Example:

```
>>> list_one = [1, 2, 6]
>>> list_two = [3, 2, 4]
>>> list(map(max, list_one, list_two))
[3, 2, 6]
```

---

How this works is that the `map` function takes 1 function as an argument, followed by 1 to n iterables; the iterables are iterated over simultaneously and their values are passed as arguments to the given function; whatever is returned from the function (`max` in this case) is yielded from the `map` into the result value.

Comment: I didn't realise that `map` was so fast! For small lists, a `map` based function runs in 2/3 the time of a function containing a list comprehension using `zip` (in Python 2); for a list of length 1000, the `map` version runs in less than half the time of the list comp. And because this version is so compact there's little point in wrapping it in a function, and of course calling it directly would be even faster.

Comment: This is fast because in Python resolving global names is slow; with list comprehension or generator expression you pay the price of finding out "*what's this `max`?*" 1000 times where the `map` does it once. Furthermore `map` does not need to rebuild tuples twice in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
[max(x,y) for x,y in zip(listOne, listTwo)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOne = [1,2,6]
listTwo = [3,2,4]

import itertools
def checkLists(listOne, listTwo):
    lsttmp=[]
    for i , j in itertools.izip(listOne,listTwo):

        lsttmp.append(max(i,j))
    return  lsttmp
print checkLists(listOne, listTwo)
```

Comment: Why import `.izip` when you can use the built-in `zip` for this? OTOH, `.izip` creates an iterator whereas `zip` creates a list, so `.izip` can be better if the input lists are very large.

Comment: @PM2Ring zip computes all the list at once, izip computes the elements only when requested.So i have used the izip

Comment: Ok. I just did some timing tests. `izip` and `zip` are roughly the same speed for very small lists, but for larger lists (>100 elements) `izip` is a little faster. However, using a list comprehension makes more of a difference: a list comp using `izip` on lists of 1000 elements runs in 2/3 the time of `zip` in a `for... append` loop.